# How to get value by class name in JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wan to retrive all the value of this code using class name. Is it possible in jQuery? I want to retrive only the text within a div or number of div may be change the next form.

```
  <span class="HOEnZb adL">
    <font color="#888888">
    </br>
    <div>
      <i><font color="#3d85c6" style="background-color:#EEE"></i>
    </div>
    <div>
       **ZERONEBYTE Software** |  
       <a target="_blank" href="http://www.example.com">
       **www.zeronebyte.com**
       </a>
       <a target="_blank" href="mailto:info@example.com">
       **info@zeronebyte.com**
       </a>
       </br>
    </div>
    <div>
     <div>
      <div>
        **+91-9166769666** | 
        <a target="_blank" href="**mailto:deepika.zeronebyte@example.com**"></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </font>
  </span>
```

Comment: Question is not clear. rephrasing needed.!

Comment: what is the desired output?

Comment: an array with all text

Comment: please clarify your question properly...

Comment: Starting with valid HTML would help. A div can't be inside a span element or font elemet. The *font* element was deprecated in HTML 4 (15 years ago) and is removed from HTML 5. Browsers will correct these errors, but probably differently so the results you get from whatever script you run in this document will likely be different in different browsers.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you get the the text inside the element use

[**Text()**](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
$(".element-classname").text();
```

In your code:

```
$('.HOEnZb').text();
```

if you want get all the data including html Tags use:

[**html()**](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
 $(".element-classname").html();
```

In your code:

```
$('.HOEnZb').html();
```

Hope it helps:)

Comment: what happens when it found multiple class with the same name?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var yourArray = [];
    $("span.HOEnZb").find("div").each(function(){
        if(($.trim($(this).text()).length>0)){
         yourArray.push($(this).text());
        }
    });
});
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/E4BkY/)</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

Without jQuery:

textContent:

```
var text = document.querySelector('.someClassname').textContent;
```

Markup:

```
var text = document.querySelector('.someClassname').innerHTML;
```

Markup including the matched element:

```
var text = document.querySelector('.someClassname').outerHTML;
```

though *outerHTML* may not be supported by all browsers of interest and *document.querySelector* requires IE 8 or higher.