# CSS selector select some part of div class name

Tags: html, css, xpath, css-selectors

Select one part of text in div class:

```
<div class="enabled_disabled disabled">
<div class="enabled_disabled">
<div class="enabled_disabled">
<div class="enabled_disabled">
<div class="enabled_disabled disabled">
```

I have those div tags, is there any xpath syntax or fizzler CSS selectors syntax to select just those div tags which have **enabled_disabled** only (the 3 in the middle)? not those with **enabled_disabled disabled**

```
var html = new HtmlDocument();
html.LoadHtml(getitems);

var doc = html.DocumentNode;
var items = (from r in doc.QuerySelectorAll("div.enabled_disabled:not(.disabled)")
    let Name = r.InnerHtml//QuerySelector("div.enabled_disabled div.title_bar div.rate_title span.name").InnerText.CleanInnerText()
    select new {
        CName = Name
    }).ToArray();
```

Comment: what you want exactly?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood correctly, but you could see this post for getting the class name: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22004818/how-to-get-value-by-class-name-in-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: @bluewonder - Look at other answers also may be it is help you

Answer (score 11):

### Fizzler

To select an element with **only** the class `enabled_disabled`, you would use:

`[class='enabled_disabled']`

Using a `:not` selector is [not available in vanilla Fizzler](https://code.google.com/p/fizzler/issues/detail?id=33), but can be used if you grab [FizzlerEx](https://fizzlerex.codeplex.com/)

### XPath

To select an element with **only** the class `enabled_disabled`, you would use:

`div[@class='enabled_disabled']`

### In plain old CSS

If the div's assigned classes **starts with** `enabled_disabled`:

`div[class^=enabled_disabled ]`

If the div's assigned classes **contains** `enabled_disabled`

`div[class*=enabled_disabled ]`

If the div **only** has the class `enabled_disabled`

`div[class=enabled_disabled ]`

If the div **has** the class `enabled_disabled` and **not** the class `disabled`

`div.enabled_disabled:not(.disabled)`

Given the HTML you list in your question, either of the last two will work for you.

[more on attribute selectors from **MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), and, [more on **:not()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

Comment: SO should provide answers to be marked as favorites, rather than questions.. +1.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, However, I tried those last 2 with doc.QuerySelectorAll (Fizzler) and doc.SelectNodes (XPATH) and I have the errors as following:  Xpath : ExceptionMessage: "'div.enabled_disabled:not(.disabled)' has an invalid token." and Fizzler : ExceptionMessage: "Unknown functional pseudo 'not'. Only nth-child and nth-last-child are supported."

Comment: The OP ask only the 3 in the middle elemnets should be select

Comment: @SW4 Yes I tried div[class='enabled_disabled'] and both div.enabled_disabled but it return all the div which includes also the (disabled) standing alone

Comment: re: https://code.google.com/p/fizzler/issues/detail?id=33, any way you would consider using FizzlerEx?https://fizzlerex.codeplex.com/

Comment: XPath equality matching would be, `div[@class='enabled_disabled']`

Comment: @SW4 I tried Fizzler EX but it also has the :not and I tried :not(.disabled) then I got the error : ExceptionMessage: "Unknown functional pseudo 'not'. Only nth-child and nth-last-child are supported.",

Comment: @bluewonder - its odd, even the original Fizzler should support some of these, did you try encapsulating the class name in `'` and `'`?

Comment: @SW4 Yes its really odd, I tried to escapsulate the class by div[class='enabled_disabled']:not(.disabled) which div[class=''] is accepted by Fizzler but it doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this selector that will match the class and will avoid the other.

```
$(".enabled_disabled:not('.disabled')");
```

and you can take out contents out of `$()`

and it is [valid css selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp)

```
 .enabled_disabled:not(.disabled)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `not()` selector in css.The `:not pseudo-class` represents an element that is not represented by its argument.

```
.enabled_disabled:not(.disabled){


}
```

[**`FIDDLE`**](http://jsfiddle.net/WTtCb/)

More about

[**SEE THE LINK**](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3anot)

Comment: The OP is after XPath / Fizzler, `:not` isnt supported

Comment: @SW4 Yes, Im using Xpath / Fizzler and this is the error message that I have : Message: "An error has occurred.",
ExceptionMessage: "'.enabled_disabled:not(.disabled)' has an invalid token.",
ExceptionType: "System.Xml.XPath.XPathException",

Comment: I also tried div[@class='enabled_disabled'] but it returns all the div tags @Sudharsan