# Get elements from source code stored in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, javascript-objects, dom-events

I have this piece of code:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
  if (request.action == "getSource") {
    message.innerText = request.source;
  }
});
```

I need to get the text from an element which is in that source code. For example, consider the page having an element like:

```
<a class="something">something goes here</a>
```

I need to get that text of class `'something'` with JavaScript. The request.source returns the source code with structure as it is.

Comment: I'm sorry but why do you ask such a basic question that has *thousands* of  answers in different flavours googlable/finadable in under 5 seconds?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get value by class name in JavaScript or jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22004818/how-to-get-value-by-class-name-in-javascript-or-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to turn the source code into jQuery object and use it like usual from there.

```
var requestedSource = request.source;
$(requestedSource).find('a.something').first().text();
```

This works for me in a very simple test on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5Lxq0n69/).

Note that you may have to play around with whatever $.find() returns if you have more than one anchor element with the class "something" (I just used $.first() to simplify my example). In that case, you can iterate through the results of $.find() like an array.

If that solution doesn't work, another (but worse) way you could do it would be to write the requested code to a hidden div, and then run $.find() from the div (though if the first solution doesn't work, there is likely something going wrong with request.source itself, so check its contents).

For example:

```
$('body').append('<div id="requestedSource" style="display: none;"></div>');
```

And then:

```
$("#requestedSource").append(request.source);
$("#requestedSource").find("a.something").first().text();
```

If you're repeating this request often, you can also empty the hidden div by calling $.empty() on it when you're done processing:

```
$("#requestedSource").empty();
```

For best performance, you would want to store everything in a variable and write once:

```
var hiddenRequestSource = '<div id="requestedSource" style="display: none;">';
hiddenRequestSource += request.source;
hiddenRequestSource += '</div>';

$('body').append(hiddenRequestSource);  

var myResults = $("#requestedSource").find("a.something").first().text();
$("#requestedSource").empty();
```

Comment: This is a generic task that has lots of answers already. In order to avoid duplication and avoid feeding the "help vampires" who are too lazy to use search it's always better to link to a good existing topic which preferably has many answers.