# How to get the element by class? htmlunit

Tags: javascript, htmlunit

I am using htmlunit to get the webpage data. And I want to get the data with the `<div class>`. But I can't find the method that is find by the class. How do I get the data?

Here is the webpage source:

```
 <div class="content-detail">
                <ul class="detail-list limited-detail">
                    <li>
                        <div class="content-sub-title">2GoGoGo Limited </div>
                            <div class="info-list">
                                <span>Tel:</span>
                                <p>+111 1111 2222</p>
                            </div>
                                                        <div class="info-list">
                                <span>Fax:</span>
                                <p>+111 1111 3333</p>
                            </div>                          
                                                        <div class="info-list">
                                <span>E-mail</span>
                                <p><a href="mailto:elaine.lee@2gotrade.com">gogogo@2gogogo.com</a></p>
                            </div>
                                                        <div class="info-list">
                                <span>Company website</span>
                                <p><a href="http://www.gogogo.com" target="_blank">http://www.2gotrade.com</a></p>
                            </div>
                                                        <div class="info-list">
                                <span>Address</span>
                                <p>Company address</p>
                            </div>
                                                          <div class="info-    list">
                                   <span>Introduction</span>
                                   <p> We are.... </p>
                            </div>
                                                                            </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

How to get the company detail on the source? thanks lot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22004818/how-to-get-value-by-class-name-in-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: page.getFirstByXPath("//span[@class='content-sub-title']");

Comment: page.querySelector(".content-sub-title");

Answer (score 2):

We can use function **getByXPath** as following.

```
getByXPath("//div[@class='class1 class2']");
```

In above example,

```
 '//' indicates to search direct and indirect element
 'div' indicates that my element is type of div
 '@class' indicates attribute name, we can use @id, @name etc.
 'class1 class2' we need to pass all class names here, only 'class1' doesn't work 
  here
```