# Get value by class name in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to fetch text by class name in jQuery. I have made a function to fetch the text of element by class name, but with this function I am getting all the text of three elements in which i have used the same class. I want to fetch the text in array like x[0] or x[1] and so on.

What can I try next?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#hide").click(function(){
          myfunction();

        });

        function myfunction(index) {
          var x = $(".check").text();

          $("#demo").text(x);}
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main">
      <p class="check">If you click on the "Hide"</p>
      <p class="check">button, I will disappear.</p>
      <p class="check">If you click on the "Hide" button</p>
    </div>
    <p id="demo">"Hide" button</p>
    <button id="hide">Hide</button>
    <button id="show">Show</button>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get value by class name in JavaScript or jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22004818/how-to-get-value-by-class-name-in-javascript-or-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array and push `text()` of each element by iterating it with `.each()`
use that array wherever you need.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
  myfunction();
  });

  function myfunction(index) {
  var array = [];
  var x = $(".check").each(function(){array.push($(this).text())});
  console.log(array);
  $("#demo").text(array);}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
<p class="check">If you click on the "Hide"</p>
<p class="check">button, I will disappear.</p>
<p class="check">If you click on the "Hide" button</p>
</div>
<p id="demo">"Hide" button</p>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use .each() jquery function and save each paragraph in an array. Run the code to see the result. Wish this answer be what you're looking for:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    myfunction();
  });

  function myfunction(index) {
    var x = [];
    $(".check").each(function() {
       x.push($(this).text());
    });
    $("#demo1").text(x[0]);
    $("#demo2").text(x[1]);
    $("#demo3").text(x[2]);
  }
});
```

```css
#main{
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="main">
<p class="check">If you click on the "Hide"</p>
<p class="check">button, I will disappear.</p>
<p class="check">If you click on the "Hide" button</p>
</div>
<p id="demo1">first check</p>
<p id="demo2">second check</p>
<p id="demo3">third check</p>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem this way

```
 //Declare an Array
    var data=[];
   /**
     * Extract data from array element
     */
    var mydata = $(".check").each(function()
    {
    data.push(
    $(this).text())
    });

   //You can access your first p tag element 
    console.log(data[0]);
```